# Selenium : wait until attribute value changed

Tags: selenium, testing, automation

I have image in webpage whose src is changed after some time there can be two possible value after src is changed(time can vary)
img_src_success or img_src_failed

I have added below code to wait until src is changed but its not working and giving error.

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 120);
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.attributeToBe(image_src, "src",img_src_success );
```

where image_src = WebElement 
src = attribute 
img_src_success = String value "/src/image/success.png"
img_src_running= String value for "/src/image/failed.png""

Above code is giving error

> org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element
>   reference: element is not attached to the page document.

Please suggest what I m doing wrong or any other way to do this.

Comment: Whenever people meet with stale element problem, I strongly suggest them to use WATIR, WATIR handles stale element problem so fine, WATIR is the wrapper which sits on Ruby Selenium Binding. If you haven't gone too far in your project, please consider using WATIR.

Comment: did u tried xpath - contains(),starts-with(),ends-with() methods ??? 
Can u show the html once of img tag ??

Comment: @shruti It is handle within loop ? If is it so, You need to share loop code with relevant HTML.

Comment: @amit ,I tried to add html image tags but it gives error that I can not post it. How  can I add contains ,starts with etc in  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.attributeToB. Can you please explain.

Comment: @Amit how does using those xpath would resolve the problem? Stale element means reference to the element is lost due page refresh or page navigation

Comment: @Ishita : No there is no loop present i just wanted to wait unitl src is changed..Will loop help ..Can you suggest with example

Comment: @Rajagopalan - You are right those xpath method will only help in giving generic xpath valid for all cases but for staleelement reference we have to catch the exception and rerun findElement command from catch block.

Comment: @Amit exactly, you are right now.

Comment: @Rajagopalan :I am using Selenium with Java...So wont be able to use WATIR

Comment: @Amit /Rajagopalan : before wait.until I searched the image element with xpath and able to print its src with the help of "getAttribute" method of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`StaleElementException` is thrown when either the element is deleted or detached from the DOM. Doing a `findElement` again might solve the issue. There is a variant of `ExpectedConditions.attributeToBe` that accepts a `By` locator. Using that ensures that the element is retrieved each time before the check is made and may resolve the issue.

You can use `wait.until` with your own `ExpectedCondition` that can fetch the element each time and also check for `StaleElementReferenceException`. Something like below:

```
    wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver input) {
            try {
                WebElement deployed_row = Report_id
                        .findElement(By.xpath("//div[(@class = 'gridxRow') and (@rowindex = '0')]"));
                WebElement table = deployed_row.findElement(By.className("gridxRowTable"));
                WebElement image_src = table.findElement(By.xpath("//tbody/tr/td[2]/div/div/span/img"));
                return image_src.getAttribute("src").equals(img_src_success);
            } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: to find image element I am using parent WebElement ,I don't have unique By locator. My piece of code is :                                                                  
WebElement deployed_row=Report_id.findElement(By.xpath("//div[(@class = 'gridxRow') and (@rowindex = '0')]"));
WebElement table = deployed_row.findElement(By.className("gridxRowTable"));
WebElement  image_src=table.findElement(By.xpath("//tbody/tr/td[2]/div/div/span/img"));

Comment: You can implement your own ExpectedCondition that can do all the findElement calls and then check for the attribute.

Comment: Yes. depending on the condition initialize your variable.

Comment: How can I use same piece of code where image src can have two values based on certain condition "img_src_success" or "img_src_failed" ? but that get decide at run time when i am waiting for element..I tried to add **if else** in place of return in try block but its not working :(